# Windows 8.1 x64 black screen on boot

Tags: windows-8.1, gpu, dual-gpu

I have done a ton of research on this already and seems to be a very common problem with 8.1. The thing I am finding is that everyone has this issue when they upgrade to win 8.1. In my case I had 8.1 working fine and wanted to add another GPU and run three monitors.

My setup right now is two monitors (1-DVI, 1-VGA) both onboard with my Intel Core i5-3470 Ivy Bridge with Intel HD Graphics 2500

I added an older Geforce 9400 GT ([support on win 8](http://www.nvidia.com/object/windows-8-solutions.html)) where I want to add another monitor. But after installing the latest NVIDIA 340.52 Driver on restart I get the black screen on all three monitors.

Anyone have any ideas? I have re installed the Intel drivers also with no luck :(

Comment: Boot into safe mode then remove the driver.

Comment: already did that.. It needs a driver to load up the third display

Comment: I have never heard of allowing on GPU to handle 2 monitors and an entirely separate GPU to handle a third only using a single GPU on all 3 that appears to be your problem

Comment: works fine with win 7, and this is a pretty common usage of two GPUs non SLI